# Getting Attribute's value from xml in c#

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have a  LINQ expression which gets the XML attribute values from a xml file.

```
 var xml = XElement.Load(@"C:\\StoreServer1.xml");
 var query = from e in xml.Descendants("Groups")
             where int.Parse(e.Element("Store").Value) == 1500
             select e.Element("Store").Attribute("WeekDayStClose").Value;
```

And the xml file is:

```
enter<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Stores>
    <Groups Range="000"> 
        <Store WeekDayStClose="210" SatStClose="21" SunStClose="22">1500</Store>
        <Store WeekDayStClose="23" SatStClose="24" SunStClose="25">18</Store>
        <Store WeekDayStClose="23" SatStClose="24" SunStClose="25">19</Store>
    </Groups> 
</Stores>
```

I am only getting the attribute result (value) for first element of 1500. If I search same thing for 18 it doesn't return any result and no exception. Any help appreciated....Plz help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Try this out:-

```
var xml = XElement.Load(@"C:\\StoreServer1.xml");
var query = xml.Descendants("Groups").Descendants("Store").Where(e => int.Parse(e.Value) == 18).Select(e=> e.Attribute("WeekDayStClose").Value);
```

Comment: You used `e.Element("Store")` instead of `Descendants("Store")` because `Element` `Gets the first (in document order) child element with the specified XName.` (source: MSDN)

Answer (score 1):

You should be more granular, call sub `Descendants` with `Store` (XName):

```
    var xml = XElement.Load(@"C:\\New Folder\\StoreServer1.xml");
    var query = from e in xml.Descendants("Groups").Descendants("Store")
                where int.Parse(e.Value) == 18
                select e.Attribute("WeekDayStClose").Value;
```

Because now you're retrieving only the ***first*** `Store` of each `Group` which is `1500`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have a little error in your code: 
You are splitting your xml into group-elements (you have just one group). Then you check if the first store element has the value 1500 (you are not checking if the following store elements have maybe the value 1500)

You need to change your code into the following

```
        var query = from e in xml.Descendants("Store")
                    where int.Parse(e.Value) == 1500
                    select e.Attribute("WeekDayStClose").Value;
```

Comment: There are only 1 `Stores`

Comment: My mistake, i meant to write "Store"